# Is e-mail communication peer-to-peer?

Tags: computer-networks

In his networking textbook, the world-renowned computer science expert Tanenbaum says that e-mail communication is inherently peer-to-peer. Here is the paragraph from the book:

> Peer-to-peer communication is often used to share music and videos. It
> really hit the big time around 2000 with a music sharing service
> called Napster that was shut down after what was probably the biggest
> copyright infringement case in all of recorded history (Lam and Tan,
> 2001; and Macedonia, 2000). Legal applications for peer-to-peer
> communication also exist. These include fans sharing public domain
> music, families sharing photos and movies, and users downloading
> public software packages. In fact, one of the most popular Internet
> applications of all, email, is inherently peer-to-peer. This form of
> communication is likely to grow considerably in the future.

I have come across several people claiming the opposite - e-mail is not peer-to-peer. They say that there is no direct connection between peers. Also, one of their argument was that if you bring one of the servers down, e-mail won't work anymore. However, logically, if Alice sends an e-mail to Bob, in my eyes, Alice and Bob are peers. Just as with regular (snail) mail, anybody can send an e-mail message to anybody. There is no distinction between clients and servers. Hence, logically, a simple two-party e-mail message is a message between two peers. The route the message traverses is irrelevant.

So, is e-mail peer-to-peer? If not, what did Tanenbaum mean by saying that?

Comment: E-mail simulates peer-to-peer communication. It is implemented using more general forms of communication. This is like saying that phoning somebody is not peer-to-peer since there are various intermediates involved. Even talking to somebody is not peer-to-peer, but for a different reason — other people could listen in. In that sense, it is more like broadcasting to an ad hoc group.